# P/Invoke method type signature error

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I've got an unmanaged function (which takes three other functions as arguments, making this extra confusing since VS does not say which function was the problem). The .NET Runtime claims that at least one of their signatures is not P/Invoke compatible (although I'm pretty sure that I marshalled everything non-trivial).

Here's my code (where TokenType is a giant enum and Failure is a small enum):

```
public enum Failure {
    UnterminatedStringLiteral,
    UnlexableCharacter,
    UnterminatedComment
};
public enum TokenType {
    OpenBracket,
    CloseBracket,
    Dot,
    Semicolon,
    Identifier,
    String,
    LeftShift,
    RightShift,
    OpenCurlyBracket,
    CloseCurlyBracket,
    Return,
    Assignment,
    VarCreate,
    Comma,
    Integer,
    Using,
    Prolog,
    Module,
    If,
    Else,
    EqCmp,
    Exclaim,
    While,
    NotEqCmp,
    This,
    Type,
    Operator,
    Function,
    OpenSquareBracket,
    CloseSquareBracket,
    Colon,
    Dereference,
    PointerAccess,
    Negate,
    Plus,
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    Minus,

    LT,
    LTE,
    GT,
    GTE,
    Or,
    And,
    Xor
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MaybeByte {
    public byte asciichar;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool present;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Position {
    public UInt32 column;
    public UInt32 line;
    public UInt32 offset;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Range {
    public Position begin;
    public Position end;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Token {
    public Range location;
    public TokenType type;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string value;
}

private delegate MaybeByte LexerCallback(System.IntPtr arg);
public delegate void CommentCallback(Range arg);
private delegate Token ErrorCallback(Position p, Failure f);

[DllImport("CAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern System.IntPtr CreateLexer(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]LexerCallback callback,
    System.IntPtr context,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]CommentCallback comment,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]ErrorCallback error
);
```

As soon as I call CreateLexer with some delegates, the runtime errors. The other answers I've seen were all about fixed-size arrays in the structs, of which I have none.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `Failure` defined?

Comment: @Damien: Oh, it's an enum. I could post the contents if you want.

Comment: it and `TokenType` are the two items that aren't obviously present in what you've shown (to my eyes, anyway)

Comment: No repro with provided source.  There's a *lot* of trouble here, too many IntPtrs, delegate types that look too fishy without an attribute that declares them cdecl and functions returning structures.  Don't try to make it all work in one go, start small.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not having declared them cdecl would almost certainly have been a problem if the C function had ever been called. Unfortunately, I added such attribute and it doesn't seem to be the problem. I could post more of my sample code, but the other interop stuff is unreached. Is it possible that the value of the delegates is a problem? I assumed that every delegate that matches the type signature would act the same way, but if some delegates have special behaviour here (I used lambdas) that would explain why you have no repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. Turns out that the marshaller was rejecting

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Token {
    public Range location;
    public TokenType type;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string value;
}
```

Apparently, you have to explicitly specify the CharSet on the struct, even though the LPStr documentation clearly states what encoding is expected. Once I set CharSet = CharSet.Ansi on the struct, the marshaller rejected something else.